# Recolher estatísticas de URL partilhado no Facebook usando Python

Tags: python, facebook, get

Para recolher as estatísticas de um URL partilhado no Facebook, em PHP, estou a fazer uso de cURL para consultar o seguinte URI:

```php
// URL para submeter
$pageUrl = 'http://www.example.com/my-new-article-is-neat';

// URI a consultar
$uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=';
$uri.= urlencode("SELECT like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count, comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"{$pageUrl}\"");

/* cURL it
 */
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $uri
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Onde obtemos:

```php
{
   "data": [
      {
         "like_count": 0,
         "total_count": 0,
         "share_count": 0,
         "click_count": 0,
         "comment_count": 0
      }
   ]
}
```

Depois podemos utilizar o resultado da seguinte forma:

```php
$respObj = json_decode($resp);

var_dump($respObj->data[0]->total_count); // int(0)
```

## Pergunta

Como posso realizar a mesma operação em Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as funções [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) para formatar a URL e [`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) para fazer a requisição e obter a resposta.

Para manipular o *JSON*, usa-se o método [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) do módulo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

```py
import urllib, json

def obterEstatisticas(url):
    parametros = urllib.quote_plus('SELECT like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count, comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "{0}"'.format(url))
    facebookURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={0}'.format(parametros)
    resposta = urllib.urlopen(facebookURL).read()
    return resposta

def main():
    url = 'http://www.example.com/my-new-article-is-neat'
    estatisticas = json.loads(obterEstatisticas(url))
    total_count = estatisticas['data'][0]['total_count']
    print (total_count)

main()
```

### [**`Exemplo`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZW9qX0dxclZ4NEU)

Em Python 3, para que o código funcione, é necessário fazer algumas alterações, por exemplo, usar [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) no lugar de [`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen).

```py
from urllib import parse, request
import json

def obterEstatisticas(url):
    parametros = parse.quote_plus('SELECT like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count, comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "{0}"'.format(url))
    facebookURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={0}'.format(parametros)
    resposta = request.urlopen(facebookURL).read()
    return resposta

def main():
    url = 'http://www.example.com/my-new-article-is-neat'
    estatisticas = json.loads(obterEstatisticas(url).decode())
    total_count = estatisticas['data'][0]['total_count']
    print (total_count)

main()
```

### [**`Exemplo`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRm5UX2xid0NtYk0)